# how to get posted object in django rest framework from a request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am almost new to django and rest framework. I want to get data on a request from client side and save a model's object. In my `view.py` file I have a class that extends from `APIView`(for example named *CreateUser(APIView)*. From the client side, I want to post a JSON file and get it in this view and save it in my models. How can I handle it?

My Student class is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    grade = models.IntegerField()
```

I have created a serializer for my Student class.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from users.models import Student


class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'grade')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.get('user')
        grade = validated_data.get('grade')
        student = Student.objects.create(self, user=user, grade=grade)
        return student
```

I want to get a JSON object with username password and grade and save it in my models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `APIView`'s post() method. To pass posted data to serializer instance use `request.data`:

```
class CreateUser(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = StudentSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

To set user password use `set_password()` inside serializer's create. Also it's a good idea to make password field `write_only`:

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'grade')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.get('user')
        grade = validated_data.get('grade')
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user, grade=grade)
        student.set_password(validated_data.get('password') 
        return student
```

**Note** `Student.objects.create` dont take `self` as first argument.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I have implemented drf docs in my project but when I go to docs. I cannot see my createuser endpoint. url(r'^signup/', CreateUser.as_view, name='create_user'),, I wrote this in my urls.py. do you know why I cannot see that?

Comment: @salehsereshki Do you set `permission_classes` for the view? Probbaly user with whom you are logged in dont have permissions to this view, and so you cannot see it in docs.